# Can sb help me to correct my vb code?

Tags: vba, vb6

```
Dim age As Integer = 1

Do While 1980 + age <> age * age
    lblResult.Text = "The solution is " & age & " years old."
    age = age + 1
Loop
```

When I run this program, it will give 44 not 45. Is there anything with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code updates `lblResult.Text` *before* it increments `age`, so when `age` is incremented from 44 to 45, the loop exits without updating the label to show the final value of `age`.

To fix the code, update `lblResult.Text` *after* incrementing `age`. Although you could do so inside the loop ...

```
Do While 1980 + age <> age * age
    age = age + 1
    lblResult.Text = "The solution is " & age & " years old."
Loop
```

... it suffices to update the label just once, after the loop finishes:

```
Do While 1980 + age <> age * age
    age = age + 1
Loop

lblResult.Text = "The solution is " & age & " years old."
```

Comment: @user3000470: You're welcome. If you'd like, click the check mark to the left to accept this answer and earn a bit of rep for yourself. :-)